# How to conditionally switch between protocol extension method implementations?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Digging into functional programming and swift overall I'm overwhelmed by multiple ways of doing things.  In this case, I'd like to have `struct` that adopts `Comparable` but can conditionally switch which properties are being used in the overloaded operators.

Let's say I have the following, a quicksort (from Niv Yahel's Wenderlich FP tutorial), extending any comparable array, which will easily accommodate my `Collection` of `Student`s

```
struct Student {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let grades: Double
}

extension Student: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
        return lhs.grades < rhs.grades
    }
    static func ==(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
        return lhs.grades == rhs.grades
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func quickSorted() -> [Element] {
        if self.count > 1 {
            let (pivot, remaining) = (self[0], dropFirst())
            let lhs = remaining.filter{ $0 <= pivot }
            let rhs = remaining.filter{ $0 > pivot }
            return lhs.quickSorted() as [Element] + pivot + rhs.quickSorted() 
            }
        return self
        }
    }
}

//Omitted, create a bunch of Students
//let bingoLittle = Student(name: "BingoLittle", age: 23, grades: 93.4)
let myStudentDirectory = [bingoLittle, studentB, ... StudentN]
let sortedStudentDirectory = myStudentDirectory.quickSorted()
```

But, what I would like for a next step is to decide on the fly which `property` the struct will be sorted by, either name, grades, or age, preferably without having to touch this nice quicksort function.

1. Should quicksort be turned into a generic function?
2. Should I be looking at type constraints?
3. Should I have a property in Student that is an enum of which property it should sort on? Seems ugly.
4. Should I have a quickSorted which is something like `quickSorted(by: .name)`? It won't seem to nicely apply to an array extension anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this:

1) use the native sort functions which let you specify a closure for the comparison and thus provides much more flexibility and doesn't require that your struct be Comparable:

```
let sortedStudentDirectory = myStudentDirectory.sorted{ $0.grade < $1.grade }

//
// This would be my recommendation given that it is standard and
// it is unlikely that the quicksorted() method would outperform it.
//
```

2) modify the quicksorted() function to let it work with a closure:

```
extension Array 
{
    func quickSorted<T:Comparable>(_ property:@escaping (Element)->T) -> [Element]
    {
        guard self.count > 1 else { return self }
        let (pivot, remaining) = (property(self[0]), dropFirst())
        let lhs = remaining.filter{ property($0) <= pivot }
        let rhs = remaining.filter{ property($0) > pivot }
        return lhs.quickSorted(property) as [Element] + self[0] + rhs.quickSorted(property) 
    }
}

let sortedStudentDirectory = myStudentDirectory.quickSorted{$0.grades}

// this one also avoids making the struct Comparable.
// you could implement it like the standard sort with a comparison
// closure instead of merely a property accessor so that descending
// sort order and multi-field sorting can be supported.
```

.

3) Add a static variable to your Student struct to tell your comparison operator which field to use and set that static variable before using the quicksorted() function

```
struct Student
{
    enum SortOrder { case name, age, grades }
    static var sortOrder = .grades
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let grades: Double
}

extension Student: Comparable 
{
    static func <(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool 
    {
       switch Student.sortOrder
       { 
          case .grades : return lhs.grades < rhs.grades
          case .age    : return lhs.age < rhs.age
          default      : return lhs.name < rhs.name 
       }
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool 
    {
       switch Student.sortOrder
       { 
          case .grades : return lhs.grades == rhs.grades
          case .age    : return lhs.age == rhs.age
          default      : return lhs.name == rhs.name 
       }
    }
}

Student.sortOrder = .grades
let sortedStudentDirectory = myStudentDirectory.quickSorted()
```

This last one is pretty bad and error prone as it will impact other comparison operations on the struct that may not intend to sort it (especially for the == operator).  It is also not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. First, `Student` should not be `Comparable`. It's not necessary and it's conceptually confusing.
2. As Alain pointed out, the `sorted` method supports the sorting of arrays that are not intrinsically `Comparable` by offering a block-based rendition, `sorted(by:)`:

   ```
   let sortedStudents = students.sorted { $0.age < $1.age }
   ```
3. You could employ the exact same pattern in your `quickSorted` method:

   ```
   extension Array {
       func quickSorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
           guard count > 1 else { return self }

           let (pivot, remaining) = (self[0], dropFirst())
           let (lhs, rhs) = remaining.reduce(into: ([Element](), [Element]())) { result, element in
               if areInIncreasingOrder(element, pivot) {
                   result.0.append(element)
               } else {
                   result.1.append(element)
               }
           }
           return lhs.quickSorted(by: areInIncreasingOrder) as [Element] + [pivot] + rhs.quickSorted(by: areInIncreasingOrder)
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you can do:

   ```
   let sortedStudents = students.quickSorted { $0.age < $1.age }
   ```

   Unrelated to your question here, but the two `filter` calls in your method seem inefficient, so I've replaced it with a single `reduce`. That (a) avoids looping through every array twice; and (b) this could be especially problematic if the comparison algorithm was complicated.

   That having been said, the build in `sorted(by:)` is much faster than this `quickSorted(by:)`, so you'd probably stick with that.

   But I assume this was more of a theoretical question of "how do I ...?" rather than "what's the best way to sort?". If that's the case, this closure pattern is a nice way of dealing with these cases.
4. If you absolutely want a sort method that takes a parameter of what field is being sorted, in Swift 4 you can use a generic function with `KeyPath`:

   ```
   extension Array {
       func quickSorted<T: Comparable>(on keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] {
           guard count > 1 else { return self }

           let (pivot, remaining) = (self[0], dropFirst())
           let (lhs, rhs) = remaining.reduce(into: ([Element](), [Element]())) { result, element in
               if element[keyPath: keyPath] < pivot[keyPath: keyPath] {
                   result.0.append(element)
               } else {
                   result.1.append(element)
               }
           }
           return lhs.quickSorted(on: keyPath) as [Element] + [pivot] + rhs.quickSorted(on: keyPath)
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you can do:

   ```
   let sortedStudents = students.quickSorted(on: \.grades)
   ```

Personally, I'd stick with the closure pattern: It’s much faster and more flexible (e.g., you could sort in descending order, you could have a complicated comparison that compared multiple properties, e.g. by age and then by name, etc.) than the keypath approach, but if you really feel compelled to pass a property, that's how you might do it.